# Locate and multiply numbers in a 2D grid (Advent of Code 2023 Day 3, Part 2)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, functional-programming, c++23

I am using the Advent of Code 2023 to study functional programming and the ranges library in C++. This code is for the second part of Day 3 and is the best solution using FB I've created. I'd appreciate comments or advice on how this code might be improved.

The input for the problem is:

```
467..114..
...*......
..35..633.
......#...
617*......
.....+.58.
..592.....
......755.
...$.*....
.664.598..
```

The challenge is to extract the values adjacent to a `*` on the same or adjacent lines.  When two numbers are near the same star, they are multiplied and summed for the final total. The example gives 467✕35 and 755✕598 for a total of 467835.

The code is in my [repo](http://tinyurl.com/3xhzhe95). I am also documenting my [activities.](http://tinyurl.com/3ac2x874)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

#include "../AdventCpp.h"
#include "inc/fp_utility.h"

#if 1
#include "inc/Trace.h"

using mys::tout, mys::nl, mys::sp, mys::tab;
#endif

namespace rng = std::ranges;
namespace vws = std::views;

using rng::fold_left;
using std::get, std::tuple, std::string_view;
using vws::split, vws::drop_while, vws::filter, vws::enumerate, //
   vws::transform, vws::take, vws::chunk_by, vws::drop, vws::filter;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// name types for better understanding in the code
// CLion shows definition using these names
using LineNUmber = int64_t;

using StarColumn = int64_t;
using StarPosition = tuple<LineNUmber, StarColumn>;
using StarRng = std::vector<StarPosition>;

using ValueColumn = StarColumn;
using ValueType = uint64_t;
using ValuePosition = tuple<LineNUmber, ValueColumn, ValueColumn, ValueType>;
using ValueRng = std::vector<ValuePosition>;

using ValStarRngs = tuple<ValueRng, StarRng>;

using ProductType = std::optional<ValueType>;
using Products = tuple<ProductType, ProductType>; // as in multiplicands

using SumType = ValueType;
using SumProducts = tuple<SumType, Products>;
#if 0
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void print_val_star_vec(ValStarRngs& val_star_vec) noexcept {

   auto& [values, stars] {val_star_vec};

   for (auto s: stars) {
      auto [l, p] {s};
      tout << code_line << "* " << l << tab << p << tab << '*';
   }
   tout << sp;

   for (auto vs: values) {
      auto [l, b, e, v]  {vs};
      tout << code_line << "V " << l << tab << b << tab << e << tab << v;
   }
}
#endif
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * The following routines parse the input to create a vectors for the stars
 * and values. The star vector contains the line an column of the star. The
 * values vector contains the line, starting and ending column, and the value.
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
constexpr auto chunk_on_digit_star = [ ](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) noexcept { //
   auto lch = get<1>(lhs);
   auto rch = get<1>(rhs);
   return !(lch == '*' or lch == '.' or rch == '*' or rch == '.');
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto remove_non_stars = [ ](auto&& tup) noexcept {
   auto ch = get<1>(tup[0]);
   return !(ispunct(ch) and (ch != '*'));
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auto extract_with_line_num = [ ](auto&& hunk, auto&& line_num) noexcept {

   // hunk is chunk of [position in line, "*" or "nnn"]
   auto [line_col, ch] {hunk[0]};

   // use std::optional to determine if there is a value in the positions
   std::optional<ValuePosition> value_position{ };
   std::optional<StarPosition> star_position{ };

   if (ch == '*') {
      star_position = StarPosition{line_num, line_col};
   } else {
      uint64_t value{ };

      for (auto h: hunk | vws::values) {
         value = (value * 10) + (h - '0');
      }
      auto end_col{line_col - 1 + hunk.size()};
      value_position = ValuePosition{line_num, line_col, end_col, value};
   }
   return tuple(value_position, star_position);
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// use currying to call extract_star_or_value with line number as argument
auto extract_star_or_value = [ ](auto&& line_num) noexcept {
   return [line_num](auto&& hunk) noexcept {
      return extract_with_line_num(hunk, line_num);
   };
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline constexpr auto
build_vectors_fn(auto&& val_star_tup, ValStarRngs& val_star_rngs) noexcept {
   auto& [value_rng, star_rng] {val_star_rngs};
   auto& [value_tup, star_tup] {val_star_tup};

   if (value_tup) { value_rng.push_back(value_tup.value()); }
   if (star_tup) { star_rng.push_back(star_tup.value()); }

   return val_star_rngs;
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto build_vectors = [ ](ValStarRngs& val_star_rngs) noexcept {
   return [&val_star_rngs](auto&& val_star_tup) noexcept {
      return build_vectors_fn(val_star_tup, val_star_rngs);
   };
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto parse_line = [ ](auto&& val_star_rngs,
                                auto&& numbered_lines) noexcept {
   auto [line_num, line] = numbered_lines;


   // process a line to get position of value or stars
   line //
   | enumerate // create tuple of {column, char}
   | chunk_by(chunk_on_digit_star)  // chunk by digits or *
   | filter(remove_non_stars) // remove chunks that are dots
   | transform(extract_star_or_value(line_num)) //
   | transform(build_vectors(val_star_rngs)) //
   | mys::eval(); // eval() is a range-for in a pipeline operator

   return val_star_rngs;
};
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * The next routines handle the calculation of the products and sum by walking
 * through the star vector. The value vector is searched for the line numbers
 * before, after, and the same as the star line. Then the position of the
 * star and value are checked for 'contact'. If two values are found they
 * become the products (multiplicands) and used to increase the sum.
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
constexpr auto drop_until_star = [ ](LineNUmber star_line) noexcept {
   return drop_while(   //
      [star_line](auto&& elem) noexcept {
         auto [value_line, _b, _e, _v] {elem};
         return value_line < std::max({ }, star_line - 1);
      });
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto value_near_star = [ ](LineNUmber star_line) noexcept {
   return filter(    //
      [star_line](auto&& elem) noexcept {
         auto [value_line, _b, _e, _v]  {elem};
         return (star_line ==
                 std::clamp(star_line, value_line - 1, value_line + 1));
      });
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto get_products = //
   [ ](StarColumn star_col, Products& products) noexcept {
      return //
         [star_col, &products](auto&& elem) noexcept {
            auto [_, value_begin, value_end, value]  {elem};

            auto clmp =
               rng::clamp(star_col, value_begin - 1, value_end + 1) == star_col;

            if (clmp) {
               auto& [lhs, rhs]  {products};

               // lhs & rhs are optionals so can test for values with var name
               if (!lhs) { lhs = value; }
               else if (!rhs) { rhs = value; }
            }
            return products;
         };
   };
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline constexpr auto summation_fn(auto&& sum_products, auto&& star_position,
                                   auto&& values_rng) noexcept -> SumProducts {

   auto& [sum, products]  {sum_products};
   auto& [star_line, star_col]  {star_position};

   rng::for_each(values_rng //
                 | drop_until_star(star_line) //
                 | value_near_star(star_line), //
                 get_products(star_col, products));

   auto& [lhs, rhs]  {products};
   sum += lhs.value_or(0) * rhs.value_or(0); // aka products

   products = { };
   return sum_products;
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// use currying to call summation with values as argument
constexpr auto summation = [ ](auto&& values_rng) noexcept {
   return [values_rng](auto&& sum_products,
                       auto&& star_position) noexcept -> SumProducts {
      return summation_fn(sum_products, star_position, values_rng);
   };
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto parse_lines(string_view const& data) noexcept -> ValStarRngs {
   auto split_enumerate{ //
      split('\n') // split into line
      | enumerate // make tuple with line number and line
   };

   // parse lines to produce ranges with star position and value position
   ValStarRngs val_star_rngs = //
      fold_left(data | split_enumerate, ValStarRngs{ }, parse_line);
   return val_star_rngs;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr auto
calculate_values(ValStarRngs const& val_star_rngs) noexcept -> SumType {
   // walk through stars range. find surrounding value lines in this range
   // and check if columns align with product values
   const auto& [values_rng, stars_rng] {val_star_rngs};

   auto [sum, _] = fold_left(stars_rng, //
                             SumProducts{{ },
                                         {Products{ }}}, //
                             summation(values_rng));
   return sum;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
execFunc execute = [ ](string_view data) {
   ValStarRngs val_star_rngs = parse_lines(data);
   return calculate_values(val_star_rngs);
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auto main() -> int {
   advent_cpp(test_data1, aoc_data, execute, 467835); // 467835 / 84907174
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Micro-review: `<cstdint>` declares identifiers in the `std` namespace, not necessarily also in global namespace.  And the existence of exact-width types depends on the platform - prefer `std::int_fast64_t` (or possibly the unsigned equivalent, here).

Comment: @TobySpeight I understand the purpose of `std::int_fast64_t`, but what would it accomplish here?

Comment: Compared to `std::int64_t`?  It's more portable, since all platforms must provide it, even if there's no exactly-64-bit type available.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes very good use of ranges and views. It looks like you are using a very heavy functional programming style. This might be unfamiliar to many C++ programmers though, and it borders on overusing this style. I'll explain why in more detail below.

## Use of type aliases

Creating type aliases helps document the use of certain types, and also makes it easier to change that type without having to search and replace through all of the code. However, you are declaring lots of them, and some of that is unnecessary.

For example, why do you have both `StarColumn` and `ValueColumn`? Because you gave them different names, it implies those types might be different. But that's never the case; they are just columns in the same input. So I would declare just `Column`. There's also `LineNUmber`, which is also used in a way very similar to `Column`. Maybe you just need one `Index` type?

Also, sometimes a type alias can hide important details of a type, which can confuse someone reading the code. For example, `ProductType` hides that it is a `std::optional` type. It might be better to not use a type alias in that case, even if it's a bit longer to type.

There are more issues with your type aliases:

## Prefer creating a `struct` over using `std::tuple`

Instead of creating `std::tuple`s, create `struct`s where possible. The main advantage is that you can give names to each member, whereas with a `tuple` you have to use `std::get<>` and remember the exact order of the tuple elements. Consider:

```
using Index = int64_t;

struct StarPosition {
    Index line;
    Index column;
};

struct ValuePosition {
    Index line;
    Index begin_column;
    Index end_column;
    ValueType value;
};
```

Note that you can still use structured bindings with `struct`s.

## Naming things

Some of your names are confusing or otherwise badly chosen:

- `StarRng`: this is a container of star positions. A range does not have to be a container. I would name this `StarPositionContainer` to be very precise about what it is. Note that you could also do this:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  using Container = std::vector<T>;

  struct Positions {
      Container<ValuePosition> values;
      Container<StarPosition> stars;
  };
  ```
- `ValStarRngs`: same as above, but you also abbreviated `Value` to `Val`. Make sure you are consistent in how you name and abbreviate things.
- `print_val_star_vec()`: first you create an alias to hide the type of container used for positions, but now you hardcode the fact that it's a vector in the name. I would name this `print_value_and_star_positions()`, or perhaps shorter `print_positions()`.
- `summation_fn()`: why put `_fn` at the end? You already know it is a function, and you don't put `_fn` at the end of the name of every other function. If it conflicts with `summation`, I would find another way to resolve the conflict.
- `build_vectors_fn()`: same.
- `summation`: function names should be verbs. I would name this `sum` or `calculate_sum`.
- `chunk_on_digit_star`: this function does not do any chunking itself, so it should not have `chunk` in its name. Also, a dot (`.`) is not a digit. Maybe `is_not_dot_or_star()` is better.
- `remove_non_stars`: the same issues. At first glance, `is_not_punctuation_except_stars()` might be a precise name. But it sounds very complicated. You can simplify it by avoiding the negation, and write an `is_punctuation_except_stars()`, and then use [`std::not_fn()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) to negate it when filtering. It's still very long, but it's better to be precise.
- `extract_with_line_num()`: extract what? I would name this `extract_value_or_star_position()`, or shorter `extract_position()`.
- `build_vectors`: again, don't add the container type to the name. Also, build a vector of what? It just adds one position, so maybe `add_position()`?
- Et cetera.

## Unnecessary use of lambdas

Named lambdas are just a complicated way of defining a function. Write a regular function instead. For example:

```
constexpr auto is_dot_or_star(auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) noexcept { //
   auto lch = get<1>(lhs);
   auto rch = get<1>(rhs);
   return lch == '*' or lch == '.' or rch == '*' or rch == '.';
};
```

Functions also have an advantage over named lambdas: you can overload them. So if you made `summation` a regular function, you could then rename `summation_fn()` to `summation()` and it would compile without problems.

## Overuse of `auto`

I see `auto&&` used a lot. This makes everything a template that accepts any type, and will take things non-`const` where possible. But you know exactly what the type of everything is here, and many parameters should not be changed, and so should be `const` (references). Also, if you know the return type, you can specify it as well. So rather write:

```
constexpr bool is_dot_or_star(const char lhs, const char rhs) noexcept {
    …
};
```

## Make use of `std::variant`

You return a tuple of two optionals from `extract_with_line_num()`. However, always exactly only one of the optionals holds a value. In that case, consider using [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in combination with [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
auto extract_value_or_star_position(auto& hunk, auto&& line_num) noexcept
-> std::variant<ValuePosition, StarPosition>
{
   auto [line_col, ch] {hunk[0]};

   if (ch == '*') {
      return StarPosition{line_num, line_col};
   } else {
      …
      return ValuePosition{line_num, line_col, end_col, value};
   }
}
```

Of course you can create a type alias for the variant:

```
using Position = std::variant<ValuePosition, StarPosition>;
```

To "build vectors", you can then write:

```
constexpr void add_position(Positions& positions, const StarPosition &position) noexcept {
    positions.stars.push_back(position);
}

constexpr void add_position(Positions& positions, const ValuePosition &position) noexcept {
    positions.values.push_back(position);
}

constexpr Positions& add_position(Positions& positions) noexcept {
   return [&](const Position& value_or_star_position) noexcept {
      std::visit([&](auto& position) {
          add_position(positions, position);
      });
      return positions;
   };
};
```

Or if you would add two `push_back()` member functions to `Positions`, one that takes a `StarPosition` and the other a `ValuePosition`, then you can just write:

```
constexpr Positions& add_position(Positions& positions) noexcept {
   return [&](const Position& value_or_star_position) noexcept {
      std::visit([&](auto& position) {        
          positions.push_back(position);
      });
      return positions;
   };
};
```

Or alternatively, you could make `Positions` a single container holding variants:

```
using Positions = Container<Position>;
```

But that would just shift the problem of separating the star and value positions to another part of the code.

## Use of `inline`, `constexpr`, `noexcept`

You use these keywords almost everywhere possible. It probably looks like a good thing to do, right? But they don't actually do anything in your code:

- `inline` on functions is just a hint for the compiler. However, nowadays compilers will aggressively inline automatically, so in almost all cases, `inline` doesn't result in any change in the output of the compiler. It just adds noise to the source code, so just omit it.
- `constexpr` ensures that it is *possible* to evaluate a function at compile time, however it doesn't force the compiler to do that. Also, everything in your program depends on input from files, so all your functions will only ever be called at runtime. So `constexpr` is not doing anything for your code, and again just adds noise to the source code.
- `noexcept` doesn't make functions that don't throw to begin with more efficient in any way. It might help in some ver specific cases, for example if you have a `noexcept` move constructor in a `class`, then a vector holding objects of that `class` might use a more efficient method of resizing its storage. But nothing like that is happening in your code. Again, it's just adding noise.

## Efficiency

There are several inefficiencies in your code. Consider this statement:

```
ValStarRngs val_star_rngs =
    fold_left(data | split_enumerate, ValStarRngs{ }, parse_line);
```

Basically, this loops over every line, parses it, and adds values and star positions to `val_star_rngs`. However, `parse_line` gets a `ValStarRngs` as input, adds some positions to it, and then returns a *copy* of the `ValStarRngs` object. So copies of vectors are made for every line you parse. That's not efficient.

A much better way would be to write it like so:

```
void parse_line(const auto& numbered_line, Positions& positions) {
   auto [line_num, line] = numbered_lines;

   for (auto& position: line
                        | enumerate
                        | chunk_by(chunk_on_digit_star)
                        | filter(remove_non_stars)
                        | transform(extract_star_or_value(line_num))) {
       add_position(positions, position);
   }
}

Positions parse_lines(string_view data) {
   Positions positions{};

   for (auto& line: data | split('\n') | enumerate) {
       parse_line(line, positions);
   }

   return positions;
}
```

Yes, that's a little less functional, not because of the `for`-loop, but because `parse_line()` has side-effects. However, it is much more efficient. You could make it functional again *and* avoid the copies, by adding a constructor to `Positions` that takes a range of `Position`s as an input, and then rewrite your code so it looks like:

```
Positions parse_lines(string_view data) {
    return data
           | split('\n')
           | enumerate
           | parse_line
           | to<Positions>();
}
```

Where `to()` is [`std::ranges::to()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to). And `parse_line` should now be a view that returns zero or more `Position` values for each input line. That should be possible to implement, but I'm not sure how to construct something like that with just the functionality from the standard library.

The call to `fold_left()` in `calculate_values()` is fine; while technically it also passes around copies, it's not a container of variable size, and the compiler will be able to optimize those copies away.

But the `for_each()` in `summation_fn()` is an issue: each time `summation_fn()` is called, it has to go through all value positions, drop all of them except for the few around `star_line`. That's a lot of wasted effort, and makes it so the complexity of your algorithm is \$O(N^2)\$. If instead you indexed your data by line, you don't need to scan-and-drop. For example:

```
Container<Positions> positions_on_lines;
```

This container would have one entry per line. So if you want to know the positions of all values on a given line number, you would just write `positions_on_lines[line_num].values`, and your algorithm would have complexity \$O(N)\$ instead.

Comment: @g-sliepen, thanks for the comments. I appreciate them and the effort you made to analyze my code. I'll look at this in detail.